# Will crontab run scripts on git branch master or main by default?

Tags: python, git, cron

Excuse me if this post should be on a forum other than stack overflow.

On a linux cluster I am running a python script 24/7 to connect to a data stream, process it, and push it to a database. A crontab file is setup to monitor that the script is running and if it stops it will be started again.

I need to edit the script and test it, so created a git branch for that. I want to make sure that if the original script (on branch main) stops, the crontab will run it and not the modified file on the new branch.

My two questions are:

1. Does crontab run scripts on main (or master) by default?
2. How can I specify the git branch of file I want to run when calling it? (Mostly for verbosity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crontab will run on a file, so, whatever state the local repo is in, whether it's updated with main/master or pulled to another branch, or edited locally, it will run that file.

If you want to explicitly run a particular branch, my advice is to point cron at a separate script, which could take the branch as a parameter, that will then prepare the script location however you want, and subsequently run it.

Comment: So the easiest solution is to create a new file? Straightforward enough but what is the point of branching for editing a file? Maybe I'm using git differently from how it is intended.

Comment: @kentkr: Git's purpose, or *raison d'être*, is to manage *commits*. A commit is a collection of files, in the form of a snapshot with history. The history is a previous snapshot (or a set of snapshots) that have history that is a previous snapshot (or set of snapshots, etc). A branch name within a Git repository exists to give you a quick and easy way to find a particular commit, which we declaim to be "the latest commit" (of that branch).

Comment: What will happen to the state of the repo after the cron script runs? For example, I am actively working in `branch-a` when the cronjob fires; if the script git switches to `main` and runs the file, will the branch I'm working on shift from under my feet?

Comment: The script will do whatever you tell it to do. If you are worried about upsetting an existing work area, maybe clone the repo to a temporary area.